# Pikaday Responsive using origin pikaday set year range not working

Tags: javascript, pikaday

i am using pikaday-responsive for the picking date, i want to set the picker for past 40 years(i.e.1976-2016), but i use the origin pikaday set "yearRange" to achieve the aim, it is not working, anyone know how to set, here is my code:

```
        var instance1 = pikadayResponsive(document.getElementById("birthday"), {
            format: "DD/MM/YYYY",
            placeholder: birthdayhint,
            yearRange: [1976,2016]
        });
```

Comment: Did you ever resolve the issue? I'm having the same problem.